# plot 3d scatterplot in R with x axis as time

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have data with time in H:M:S format, lattitude and longitude. I need to plot a 3D scatterplot with them.
The time is not at regular intervals.

I have tried using plotly with following code:

```
library(readxl)
bus1<-read_excel('example.xlsx',col_names=TRUE)
x<- as.POSIXct(bus1$Time,format = '%H:%M:%S')
y<-bus1$Lattitude
z<-bus1$Longitude
library(plotly)

plot_ly(x=x , y=y , z=z ,type="scatter3d",mode="lines",
       colors = c('#BF382A', '#0C4B8E')) %>%
       add_markers() %>%
       layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'Time'),
                        yaxis = list(title = 'Lattitude'),
                        zaxis = list(title = 'Longitude')))
```

This is giving me some weird plot with very few data points.

Output for this:
[image: Output for this]

Comment: Can you please add some sample data? Ty! (some rows to try on) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your `plotly` syntax looks problematic. The tilde operator `~` is often needed. For example:

```
plot_ly(~z, type="scatter")
```

You should check out [this free tutorial by DataCamp](https://www.datacamp.com/community/open-courses/plotly-tutorial-plotly-and-r#gs.kgQOIP0). I found its exercises to be helpful.